# ReactJS Canvas Context not rendering Image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blender, gsap

I got a blender model exported as JPEG images (175 frames). I'm trying to draw image from a frame with gsap and smooth scrolling as images are for scrolling 3d models.

```
import './App.css';
    import React from 'react';
    import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import gsap from 'gsap';
    
    function App() {
      const canvas = React.useRef();
    
      canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
      canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    
      let ball = {frame : 0};
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const context = canvas.current.getContext('2d'); 
        const frameCount = 175;
        
        const currentFrame = (index) => `./ball/${(index+1).toString()}.jpg`;
        const images = []
        for(let i=0; i < frameCount; i++){
            const img = new Image();
            img.src = currentFrame(i);
            images.push(img);
          }
          console.log(images)
    
          context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
          
          images[0].onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(images[ball.frame], 0, 0)
          }
      })
    
    
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h2 className='ball-text'>Ballzy Design.</h2>
          <canvas 
            ref={canvas}
            width="100"
            height="100"
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

I can see the context value and image array, path, and everything when I do the console log but it only fails when I add the function in images on load. When I do the console.log on onLoad it works and will show the log but doesn't render the image. Is it a bug with context?